# Python3 and python2 on package

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, catkin, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have in my ROS package nodes that are supposed to be run with python2 and with python3. I wanto to maintain common code in shared libraries, a python2/3 lib and a python3 only lib. I read that I can keep my python packages on the `/src` folder and write a `setup.py` file so the packages would be installed and available to my nodes  when a run `catkin_make` or `catkin build`.

The question is, how can I install both python3 and python2/3 packages in the same setup file?
This could be done by catkin? If no, what would be the better way of organizing my code in this situation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352665/python3-and-python2-on-package/) by [czr](https://answers.ros.org/users/54143/czr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When a package is being built it uses one specific Python interpreter. There is no option to perform *two* builds - one with Python 2 and one with Python 3.

A package can contain Python code though which works just fine with Python 2 as well as 3. Since the setup files extend the `PYTHONPATH` you can use the packages Python API with both Python versions afterwards.

For a whole ROS distribution the decision of the Python major version is being made for the packaging of binary packages. For ROS 1 Melodic and older Python 2 is being used. For ROS 1 Noetic Python 3 is being used.

Maybe you can describe your concrete use case in more detail for a specific feedback.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [czr](https://answers.ros.org/users/54143/czr/) on 2020-06-03**:
I saw some tutorials teaching to use Python3 with ROS melodic, but I realized that it is not worth it. My use case is that I wanted to use a model from Detectron2 (PyTorch) library but it only supports python 3, so I wanted to have two packages, one for python2/3 other python3 only. But I decided to use Mxnet/GluonCV instead since they still support python2.